# Initialization of a structure that contains a pointer to an array

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have the following structure:

```
typedef struct TRIE_NODE
{
    char* word;
    struct TRIE_NODE* node[26];
}TRIE_NODE;
```

I create a node called head, `TRIE_NODE *head = NULL;`, and then i try to initialize this node using the following function:

```
void initialize_node(TRIE_NODE *current_node)
{
    int MAX = 25;

    current_node = malloc(sizeof(TRIE_NODE));

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
    {
        current_node->node[i] = NULL;
        if(current_node->node[i] == NULL)
            printf("\n -- \n");
    }
}
```

However, i get a segmentation fault whenever i try to even read `current_node->node[i]`. Does anyone have any idea of what's going on? Considering `current_node->node` is a pointer, that points to another pointer of type `TRIE_NODE`, shouldn't i be able to access it's values through bracket notation? (I've tried dereferencing it too, it doesn't compile)

Comment: `node` is an array of pointers, not a pointer to an array! Not clear what you want to accomplish. An array is not a pointer and vice-versa!

Comment: @Olaf Doesn't `node` point to a chunk of memory that can hold 26 units of `TRIE_NODE` ? I'm just trying to initialize those 26 units to null.

Comment: I think I was vry clear in my comment. **No** it does not!

Comment: @Olaf I don't have the knowledge to understand what you mean, if these questions are too simple for this forum i'll gladly go elsewhere. I know pointers and arrays are not the same, and i can't see where i said that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do everything correctly, except this line

```
current_node = malloc(sizeof(TRIE_NODE));
```

which modifies the local copy of `current_node`. The pointer in the caller remains unchanged.

To fix this problem, pass a pointer to pointer, and assign with an indirection operator:

```
void initialize_node(TRIE_NODE **current_node_ptr) {
    ...
    *current_node_ptr = malloc(sizeof(TRIE_NODE));
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think i understand what's wrong, my code is not compiling yet but let me if my logic is right. I was changing the local copy, that makes sense, so now i'll send `&head`, considering head is already a pointer, right? And then deal with `*current_node`  everytime i would deal with `current_node` directly.

Comment: @Selhar Yes, that's correct. You need to add parentheses around `*current_node_ptr`, e.g. `(*current_node_ptr)->node`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only it worked but i understood what i did wrong.